# Wordpress Not Working properly

Tags: html, wordpress

Iam working with wordpress. When click on the menu it goes to html page.

Unknowingly I unzipped the html folder with the same name  of the wordpress folder. Now the html code has merged with the wordpress folder. How can I get  my wordpress site back again ? where I have to change ? in database or code ?

Comment: in which directory you unziped the html code

Comment: if its in main directory the delete all without wp-config.php and wp-comtent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution first compress the `wp-content` folder in your wordpress installation main directory. Then take a backup of your `wp-config.php` then delete all on that directory but keep the `wp-conten`t and `wp-config.php` now download a fresh copy of wordpress upload it and extract the new uploaded wordpress. you will find a new `wp-content` folder in new wordpress you just extracted. now delete the new `wp-content` and unzip the old `wp-content` and upload the `wp-config.php`  you are done.  :P  if there is any discrepancy please feel free to contact.

Comment: If this answer help you try to accept ans and give up ⬆ vote